# Convert JSON to Typescript Interface including Date method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

On Angular 7 I have the following Post Model:

```
export interface PostModel {
  id: number;
  created: Date;
  published: boolean;
  title: string; 
}
```

And I have the following Angular service method to get posts:

```
public getPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

  return this.httpClient.get<PostModel[]>(url).pipe(

    map((post: PostModel)) => {

      return {
        id: post.id, 
        created: new Date(post.created),
        published: post.published,
        title: post.title
      };

    })

  };
```

I am converting the API response to `PostModel` manually ...

This is because `created` type is Date and Angular does not converts it automatically.

I would like to reuse the mapping code in different parts of my code:

```
map((post: PostModel)) => return mapPostFromJson(post));
```

I could convert PostModel to class and mapPostFromJson as its method.

But I would prefer `PostModel` to keep being an interface.

How can I do this?

**Update**

My problem is how to create the mapPostFromJson method. I tried:

```
mapPostFromJson(data: any) : PostModel {

  return map((post: PostModel) => {

    return { 
      id: post.id, 
      created: new Date(post.created),
      published: post.published,
      title: post.title
    };

  });

}
```

This function does not compile ...

I am not sure how to use map outside pipe ...

Comment: What's the *problem* with what you have? Is there something specific preventing you from assigning that callback to the name `mapPostFromJson`?

Comment: I can't place the method mapPostFromJson inside the PostModel because it is an interface ... Not sure the best way to create the mapPostFromJson method to use in different services.

Comment: But in the example *you've posted*, `map((post: PostModel)) => return mapPostFromJson(post));`, it's just a function - what stops you doing that? It's *already* a function, just an anonymous one (and it doesn't need any context, so you could do `.map(mapPostFromJson)`).

Comment: Maybe I am explaining my self wrong but what I am looking os for the code of mapPostFromJson ... Maybe I am making some confusion here but basically it is the code of that function I am looking for.

Comment: You **already have that code**, you've included it in the question. You're currently passing it straight to map as an anonymous arrow function.

Comment: I updated my question to better explain what is my problem ... Does it help?

Comment: Not really; that's not syntactically a function, and it's unclear what you're expecting `map` to do inside it (*"I am not sure how to use map outside pipe"* - why do you think you *need* to?) I'd recommend going back over basic JS syntax and specifically ES6 arrow functions. It also looks like you have a problem with the original code, which treats an array of objects like it's a single one of those objects - I think you're confusing observable map with array map. The short answer is to extract the arrow function to the name you want; your editor/IDE may be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but, would that mapping function work?

```
mapPostFromJson(data: any): PostModel {
    return { 
        id: data.id, 
        created: new Date(data.created),
        published: data.published,
        title: data.title
    };
}
```

Otherwise, using functional principles, you could make a more generic solution by defining general functions that you can reuse to build your mappers:

```
// This function takes a structure of functions, and applies
// them to some data, returning a structure of the results
const mapper = functions => json => Object.entries(json)
    .map(([k, val]) => ({ [k]: (functions[k] || (x => x))(val) }))
    .reduce((acc, o) => Object.assign(acc, o), { });
```

You can then easily create a mapper and call it on your JSON:

```
// create a mapper that passes all properties
// but transforms 'created' to a date
const mapPostFromJson = mapper({
    created: x => new Date(x)
});

const post = mapPostFromJson(jsonPost);
```

Using this mapper, all JSON properties will pass through, but the created field will be transformed to a date.